# Code completion on Vue/Typescript library not working on IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm building a `Vue.js / Vuetify / Typescript` library in ordre to share and reuse components across multiples projects.

The library is built with `Vite / npm`, it works fine but I don't have any code completion on IntelliJ when used as a npm dependency, neither on components name nor on props.

Code completion is working flawlessly with Vuetify's components on IntelliJ, so I guess IntelliJ should be able to do the same for my custom library.

Here's a sample of my `package.json` file :

```json
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "main": "./dist/ui-components-lib.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/uicomponents-lib.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/ui-components-lib.js",
      "require": "./dist/ui-components-lib.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  }
```

and the `vite.config.ts` :

```
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'UiComponents',
      fileName: `ui-components-lib`,
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Everything seems good inside the tarball (generated with `npm pack`) : all the `d.ts` type files are under `dist\types`.

But still no code completion.
Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not always possible to resolve components defined in third-party libraries using static code analysis. To improve code completion for different **Vue.js** component libraries, we have invented a special format of metadata, called `web-types`. [web-types](https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types) describe the library's components and their directives.

If you're maintaining your own **Vue.js** component library, you can add description of the components in the `web-types` format to your module. To help the IDE to locate this file, a link to it should be added to the `"web-types"` field in `package.json`.

On http://github.com/JetBrains/web-types you can find the JSON schema, instructions on generating the metadata in the required format, as well as the latest versions of descriptions for the most popular Vue.js component libraries

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've tried with a very small web.types.json file : `{"$schema":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/web-types/master/schema/web-types.json","framework":"vue","name":"test-lib","version":"1.0.1","js-types-syntax":"typescript","contributions":{"html":{"elements":[{"name":"MyAlert","source":{"symbol":"MyAlert"},"attributes":[{"name":"type","value":{"kind":"expression","type":"string"}}]}]}}}`. The package.json references this file. But in the project using the library, there is still not code completion. Something wrong with it ?